# use same frame in android

Tags: android

I am developing a chat application where in i want all the online chat users to be displayed horizontal on the top with the scroll.This is possible.
But what i require is if a click on any of these users a page similar to spark should b visible.
Is it possible to dynamically add something to layout inflator in android.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Well you could just place these elements in a listview of sorts.  Perhaps an image for each.  When you click what will happen is you can issue an Intent which an activity will filter on.  Or you can launch a dialog.  Basically what you need to do is create a listview with horizontal orientation.  Then create customer adapter.  Use this custom adapter to return view that with registered event handler for each row.  Event handler like onClick issues Intent.  Some Activity has filter for it and it will go there.  Perhaps you need a dialog to show ro some other ui element.  It just needs to filter on this event.  You could also broadcast if needed.

Comment: What i require is to load these intents dynamically without mentio ning in the manifest.Dynamically create an intent and pass it.Is it possible in android